# Can we apply binomial theorem for $\quad(a+b)^\ell\quad$ if $\ell\;$ irrational.

Tags: irrational-numbers, binomial-theorem

Let be$\quad a,b\;\in\mathbb R\quad, \ell\;\in\mathbb {(R\backslash Q)} \quad $ ($\ell:$irrational)

Can we apply binomial theorem for $\quad(a+b)^\ell$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:
$$
(a+b)^{l}=a^{l}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{l}{k}\bigg(\frac{b}{a}\bigg)^k 
$$
Binomial coefficients are calculated as the regular ones. 
$$
\binom{\alpha}{k}=\alpha \cdot (\alpha-1) \cdots (\alpha-k+1) \cdot \frac{1}{k!}
$$

More information is provided on the Wikipedia page, linked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: Thanks a lot , for interesting ,and answer,and all of :)